# Mysql - Grab default records if specific records arent found

Tags: php, mysql

Using MySQL and php how would I, in a single query, grab all results matching a certain query but if no results found it then finds all the default results? For example I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE typeid = 5
```

If no results are found from the query below then I want to find all results from table1 with the typeid of 1:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE typeid = 1
```

How can I do that in a single query? If I try the following query I get both 5 and 1:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE typeid = 5 OR typeid = 1
```

All I want to to is query table1 for all records assigned with typeid of 5, if no results found then get all results assigned to typeid = 1 in a single query. How can I do that? Or do I have to have 2 queries?

**EDIT**

I need this for multiple records returned, not a single record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  typeid = IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE typeid = 5), 1, 5);
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table1 WHERE typeid = 5) > 0 THEN
    typeid = 5
ELSE
    typeid = 1
END;
```

Comment: @eggyal: Just in time, too...this one had me scratching my head for a minute. Wasn't sure if you could use conditionals in the `WHERE` clause. I've only ever used them in the `SELECT` part.

Comment: +1 Nice. This works for multiple rows. Technically, I think you could leave off > 0 part.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Good point, since `0` and `FALSE` are the same thing in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE typeid = 5
  UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE typeid = 1
      AND NOT EXISTS
          ( SELECT * 
            FROM table1 
            WHERE typeid = 5
          ) ;
```